# Find the differential equation relating \$v(t)\$ and \$i(t)\$

Tags: capacitor, inductor

Find the differential equation relating \$v(t)\$ and \$i(t)\$ of the AC circuit in the following figure.
[image]

My approah:
Considering the inductor:
$$ v(t) = L\frac{di_{L}}{dt} $$
$$i_L = \frac{1}{L}\int v_{(t)} \,\mathrm{dt}$$

Considering the capacitor:
$$i_{C} = C\frac{dv_{(t)}}{dt}$$

$$\therefore i_{(t)} = i_{L} + i_{C}$$
$$i_{(t)} = \frac{1}{L}\int v_{(t)} \,\mathrm{dt} + C\frac{dv_{(t)}}{dt}$$
$$\frac{d^2v_{(t)}}{dt^2} - \frac{1}{C}\frac{di_{(t)}}{dt} + \frac{1}{LC}v_{(t)} = 0$$

Is this correct? Please correct me.

Comment: May want to use \$\text{d}t^2\$ in the denominator of the first term.

Comment: @jonk thanks for pointing that.

Answer (score 1):

I think there is a sign error in the current equation and therefore sign errors in the final result. If the direction of v(t) was flipped, the result would be correct i think.

Comment: Arrow indicates the positive side of the voltage. So there's no sign error.

Comment: Interesting, i didn't know there was any controversy in the convention about the voltage arrow direction. I learned that the arrow is pointing from positive to negative potential. So i would argue that the positive potential would be in the right side of the figure. Is there any international norm or highly reliable textbook covering this?

Comment: Yes, it's called "passive sign convention".

Answer (score 1):

There is a sign error in your solution. Note, that i(t) and v(t) are not on the same direction. Thus i(t) = -(i_L(t) + i_C(t)).

You could verify your solution by applying Laplace transform. The complex impedance of L and C in parallel is s*L/(s^2*L*C+1) and therefore we have V=-s*L/(s^2*L*C+1)*I (the negative sign is due to the different directions of V and I). A little bit of algebra gives

s^2*V + 1/(L*C)*V = - s*I/C

Remembering that the multiplication with s is equal to taking the derivative, you end up with the differential equation.

Comment: Arrow indicates the positive side of the voltage. So there's no sign error.

Comment: Yes, there is a sign error. If both voltage and current arrows point in the same direction, we have U=Z*I. If they point in different directions the equation is U=-Z*I.

Comment: Please google "passive sign convention" and you'll get what I'm trying to say.

Comment: Obviously, not the same convention is used in all the countries! In Europe (or at least in the German speaking countries), if the voltage arrow points from A to B, the voltage V_AB is the difference of the potentials at A minus the potential at B. This means, that if V_AB>0 then the potential at point A is higher than that at point B. It seems that in the USA (or may be the English speaking countries), the contrary convention is used.

Comment: I have never seen this German convention usage of the arrow for specifying \$v(t)\$, so I agree with @RohatKılıç regarding it not having a sign error. But in the end it is up to the OP to figure what notating is being used in the book he's using.

Comment: I agree with jDAQ that in the end, it is a matter of convention and thus must be clarified. However, as I own a couple of German books on this subject, I can assure you that all of them agree that in a "Verbraucherzählpfeilsystem" (which I would translate as passive sign convention) the arrows of voltage and current point in the same direction and in this case, Ohm's law is \$U = R\cdot I\$. Since I used this convention during the last 40 years, I was rather surprised to learn myself, that this is not a global convention.